# animating the layout's setRotation property

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

views can be rotated using the `RotateAnimation` object in android, but using this class seems to only visually rotate the views, e.g. clicking the rotate view(rotated with pivot other than center) would not actually click the view, the view is still in it's original position but is only *visually* somewhere else.

Hence, in order to rotate the view along with it's children to a new position, I found the solution to use `layout.setRotation(angle)`, in my case `layout` is a `constraintLayout` which I'll have to rotate through `180`.

But, the problem is, that I am not being able to animate this, I'd like to make a smooth transition from `0` to `180` degrees, but it just snaps to 180 degrees. How can I animate this property or possibly the rotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .xml file inside the Constraint Layout add the following code.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
```

MainActivity.java :

```
 ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
 constraintLayout.animate().rotation(100).setDuration(2000);
```

The only problem was that you forgot to add .animate() before .rotation() and that's why it didn't work.

Comment: I need to animate the layout at run time. Wouldn't this hardcode the rotation during the inflation itself?

Comment: I have edited my answer and added the java code and removed the rotation in the .xml file. Hope it works.

Comment: The only problem was that you forgot to add .animate() before .rotation() and that's why it didn't work.

Comment: this is working great! but, how do I set the pivot for rotation. in `RotateAnimation` we could set it by using pivotX, pivotY and `Animate.RELATIVE_TO_SELF`, is there something similar for this?

Comment: You can add an onImageClicked() function in which starts when we click the screen code is.ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
                                    constraintLayout.animate().animate().translationYBy(180).translationXBy(180).setDuration(2000);                                                                                                           Then in onCreate function add: `constraintLayout.setX(-1000);
                                constraintLayout.animate().translationXBy(1000).rotation(3600).setDuration(2000);`     This should work and I hope it helps.

Comment: @Thanks, that really helped, do you also know the answer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63649801/rotating-a-constraintlayout-and-rotating-constraints-as-well

Comment: If the other question worked then that's great. Also can you please answer this question because I have asked it twice but no one has ever answered : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63653963/parse-is-unable-to-delete-the-objects-which-i-want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63653963/parse-is-unable-to-delete-the-objects-which-i-want)

Comment: I've only use SQLiteObjects for backend so far, (I'm not really that advanced), is this ParseQuery related to Sqlite?

Comment: It is related, they both are databases, but they have different code.