# rotating a constraintLayout and rotating constraints as well

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I can visually show what I mean to do:
[image]

basically, something like:

> `app:layout_constraintBottom_toEndOf` is Illegal

But, I'd like to know if there's a  way to implement this sort of dynamic remapping of constraints that would in turn also rotate the views inside of the constraintLayout

Answer (score 2):

I've used external library from https://github.com/rongi/rotate-layout It allows to rotate viewgroup's children.

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/hello_string"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.25"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.75"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.96" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Button3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.96"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Button4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.03"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textCoord"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Preview Child Not Rotated :

[image]

Preview Child Rotated

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for nested constraint layouts? i.e. wrapping constraint layout with children in the above layout

Comment: Check [this](https://medium.com/devnibbles/constraintlayout-circular-positioning-9489b11cb0e5) to get an idea or get your answer.

Comment: but, this is not quite what I had in mind. It's just placing thing around a radius, not rotating the bounding box of the child

Comment: I was trying to read the source code, but then there were some trouble in methods I didn't understand. Perhaps you know how these work? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63724623/what-does-getmeasuredstate-return-and-how-does-it-work-with-combinemeasuredsta