# Parse is unable to delete the objects which I want

Tags: android, android-studio

In my app which I am working on, there is a place where you can cancel a donation request, so if they cancel a donation I want to remove it from thee database, but it is not able to delete. Also there is no chance that object isn't in the database because it has just been opened from the requests screen before. Here is the code for the cancel function :

```
    public void cancel(View view){

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Are you sure you want to cancel this request?")
            .setMessage("It is unchangeable")
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ArchivedRequests");
                    query.whereEqualTo("donorUsername", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
                    query.whereEqualTo("ngoUsername", ngoUsername);
                    query.whereEqualTo("requestsDate", date);
                    query.whereEqualTo("requestTime", time);
                    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null){
                                if (objects.size() > 0){
                                    for (ParseObject object : objects){

                                        object.deleteInBackground();

                                        Toast.makeText(DateChangeActivity.this, "Inform your NGO that you have cancelled the request!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                        Intent intent = new Intent(DateChangeActivity.this, DonorChatActivity.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("ngo", ngoUsername);
                                        intent.putExtra("ngoN", ngoName);
                                        intent.putExtra("class", "donor");
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show();
}
```

I hope you can tell me how to fix this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you've used deleteInBackground(), have you used something that doesn't do things in the background?